# Python get diff for ConfigParser

Tags: python, configuration, configuration-files, configparser

Let say I have old and new configurations initialized

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

old_config = ConfigParser()
old_config.read(config_file1)
new_config = ConfigParser()
new_config.read(config_file2)
```

How can I get the difference between these two configs?

Comment: You'll have to write some code. There are unlikely to be automatic tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn each of the config instances into a dictionary using:

```
old_dict = old_config._sections
new_dict = new_config._sections
```

then get the difference using:

```
set(old_dict.items()) ^ set(new_dict.items())
```